# How can I retrieve the response text from the json file not working using jquery

Tags: jquery, json, ajax

Am trying to get the response text from the json file but am able to get the object in which there is response text
The json data is:

```
 var response = [{
"id": 1,
"name": "Web Demo"
  }, {
   "id": 2,
   "name": "Audio Countdown"
 }, {
   "id": 3,
   "name": "The Tab Key"
 }, {
   "id": 4,
    "name": "Music Sleep Timer"
 }, {
    "id": 5,
    "name": "Music Sleep Timer"
}];
```

and jquery Ajax code as follows

```
       var request = $.ajax({
                    url: "data.json",
                    type: "GET",            
                    dataType: "application/json"
              });
```

I tried by keeping .responseText after request but am not able to get the only response text how can get it am able to return object

Comment: Please create jsfiddle link for the same. So one can look into the issue and provide solution.

Comment: I'm considering to delete my comment as it's not clear where the problem is exactly. Can you please describe how exactly are you handling the response form server?

Comment: **[`Works good here`](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/9vsdxoha/)**.. Bdw, how have you written your `success` callback?

Comment: @GuruprasadRao  I have not given any success call back whatever I have shown in the question is my code so  how can I give success callback to return responsetext from json object

Comment: Check the link I've given in my previous comment!!

Comment: @GuruprasadRao  Am able return object how can I retreive only responseText from that object

Comment: remove `var request=$.ajax`, just keep `$.ajax`. I wonder why you are returning `var response`, why don't you just pass necessary `data` as shown in the demo?

Comment: @GuruprasadRao  Thank you

Comment: That is not JSON data if it has `var response =`

Answer (score 1):

Please you have to correct your json data format.....

```js
    
$(document).ready(function () {
 
GetLiList();
  
});

function GetLiList() {

        data = '[{"id" : "1", "name" : "Web Demo"},{"id" : "2", "name" : "Audio Countdown"},{"id" : "3", "name" : "The Tab Key"}]';

        var response = JSON.parse(data);
        var counter = 0;
        for (counter = 0; counter <= response.length; counter++) {
            $('#users .list').append('<li id="' + response[counter].id + '"><h3 class="name">' + response[counter].name + '</h3></li>')
        }
    }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>


<div id="users">
    <ul class="list"></ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I want it using jquery ajax not using json data internally

Answer (score 0):

try to use getJSON():

```
 $.getJSON( "data.json", function( data ) {
 var items = [];
 $.each( data, function( key, val ) {
  items.push( "<li id='" + key + "'>" + val + "</li>" );
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use simply getJSON method of jquery like below,

```
$.getJSON( "data.json", function( data ) {
// write your logic here.

});
```

Answer (score 0):

if you would like to retrieve just a text, then modify the contentType.

```
 var request = $.ajax({
                    url: "data.json",
                    type: "GET",            
                    dataType: "text/plain"
              });
```